# RedirectToAction not working when called by jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, redirecttoaction

I am trying to call an action method by jQuery, and got help with passing parameters here: [Calling action method in MVC with jQuery and parameters not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542333/calling-action-method-in-mvc-with-jquery-and-parameters-not-working) . However, even though the parameters are sent correctly now, in the action method I need to redirect (passing on those same parameters) to another action method. In the debugger I can see that the redirect is carried out, and the parameters are still there, but the View returned doesn't update accordingly...

Is there some problem with calling an action method that redirects by using jQuery?

Action method called by jQuery:

```
    public ActionResult SelectDate(string date)
    {
        DateTime dateObject = DateTime.Parse(date);
        MyCalendar calendar = new MyCalendar();

        string number =  calendar.GetWeekNumber(dateObject).ToString();
        string year = dateObject.Year.ToString();
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { number = number, year = year });
    }
```

Action method redirected to:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(string number, string year) //Why string here???
    {
        int n;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(number))
            n = myCalendar.GetWeekNumber(DateTime.Today);
        else
            n = Int32.Parse(number);

        int y;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(year))
            y = DateTime.Today.Year;
        else
            y = Int32.Parse(year);

        List<Customer> customers = _repository.Customers;
        ViewData["Customers"] = new SelectList(customers, "CustomerId", "CustomerName");

        ViewData["WeekNumber"] = n;
        ViewData["Year"] = y;

        return View();
    }
```

Or is jQuery get() not the proper way to call an action method to load a new page? Note that doing the same thing with an ActionLink works fine, it's just that I need to call it by jQuery because I'm using the datepicker plugin and also a button as the way to call the action.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Actually, the RedirectToAction doesn't seem to be the problem, I modified the code so that the jQuery now calls the final action method directly (by doing the job of the first action method directly in the jQuery, i.e. convert date to week and year). But I still don't get the new page with the new week and year.

Here's the new jQuery:

```
    function selectWeek() {
        $('#selectWeekButton').click(function (event) {
            var date = $('#selectWeekId').val();
            var selectedDate = new Date(date);
            var year = selectedDate.getFullYear();
            var week = selectedDate.getWeekOfYear();
            var url = '<%: Url.Action("Edit") %>';
            $.get(url, { number: week, year: year }, function (data) {
                //                    alert('Test');
            });
        });
    }
```

Again, is it using the get that is incorrect? I do not wish to load content in an html tag, I just want to use jQuery to do the exact same thing as an actionlink, i.e. call an action method to get the Edit View...

For instance, this actionlink works fine, calling an action method called Next that redirects to Edit and shows the new week and year View:

```
<a href="<%=Url.Action("Next", new { number=ViewData["WeekNumber"], year = ViewData["Year"]   })%>">
            &gt;&gt;</a>
```

But I want to do that (or Edit directly) in jQuery...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jquery AJAX automatically follows redirect meaning that in the success callback you will get the result of the `Edit` action you have redirected to. In this callback you will get the partial HTML returned by the controller action. So if you want to update some part of the DOM you need to explicitly instruct it so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<%= Url.Action("SelectDate") %>',
    data: { date: '123' },
    success: function(result) {
        $('#someresultDiv').html(result);
    }
});
```

or simply use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

```
$('#someresultDiv').load('<%= Url.Action("SelectDate") %>', { date: '123' });
```

Comment: @Anders Svensson, don't use AJAX if you are going to redirect. You are missing the whole point of AJAX. AJAX is used to when you need to update only parts of the page without redirecting/reloading the whole page. If you need to redirect don't use AJAX, put a simple anchor link.

Comment: @Darin: Right, I suspect there is something wrong with that, I know, but how then am I supposed to do the same as an actionlink, and at the same time pass along the parameters needed (and taken from an input field set by a datepicker jQuery plugin)? Is there some other jQuery call to an action method that does the same as an actionlink, that is not get() or ajax?

Comment: @Anders Svensson, don't use AJAX if you don't need it: use a simple ActionLink.

Comment: Ok, but again then: how do I achieve the following two with an ActionLink: 1. Having a button instead of a link. 2. Passing the parameters needed - the date from the field set by the jQuery datepicker plugin?

Comment: @Anders Svensson, achieve what?

Comment: Well, what I just wrote above: passing the parameter date string taken from the input field set by the datepicker plugin to the action method (and also using a button instead of a hyperlink, cosmetic, but still)... As you can see, the parameters should not simply be ViewData as in the example actionlink above, but a parameter taken from an input field. And I only know how to get that value by jQuery...